# ListPreference onClickListener takes twice to execute

Tags: android, onclicklistener, preference

So I'm having this problem where my ListPreference takes two clicks upon it, to actually do what's in the onClick listener. Here's my code

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    final ListPreference prefListThemes = (ListPreference) findPreference("prefMaterialThemes");
    prefListThemes.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("Test prntln");
            // Restart Activity to apply Theme
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As you can see what I'm trying to do is just a simple restart of the app to apply my theme. At first I thought it might be that intent code causing the problem, but even when I have just a toast in that onclick listener you still have to click the list preference, select an option, then click the preference again, and select the option once more for it to actually do anything. If you could help that would be great. Thank You!

SettingsActivity which gets the preferences from preferences.xml

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.CheckBoxPreference;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.content.IntentCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.iliakplv.notes.R;
import com.iliakplv.notes.gui.main.LauncherActivity;
import com.iliakplv.notes.gui.main.MainActivity;

import java.util.List;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    private static final int PREFERENCES = R.xml.preferences;

    private final static String PREFS_LIST_OF_THEMES = "prefMaterialThemes";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //noinspection deprecation
        addPreferencesFromResource(PREFERENCES);
        PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, PREFERENCES, false);

        // These 3 lines are required for the onSharedPreferenceChanged method
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        // End
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

        final CheckBoxPreference prefDarkThemeCB = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("prefDarkTheme");
        prefDarkThemeCB.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (prefDarkThemeCB.isChecked()) {
                    // Restart Activity to apply Theme
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else if (prefDarkThemeCB.isChecked() == false) {
                    // Also restart activity to apply default theme
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        final ListPreference prefListThemes = (ListPreference) findPreference("prefMaterialThemes");
        prefListThemes.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Toasted");
                // Restart Activity to apply Theme
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                return false;
            }
        });

        final CheckBoxPreference prefRequirePasswordCB = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("prefEnablePasswordLock");
        prefRequirePasswordCB.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (prefRequirePasswordCB.isChecked()) {
                    EditTextPreference prefUsersPass = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prefPassword");
                    // Check to see if the users password is empty before allowing them to check the require password box
                    if (prefUsersPass.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        prefRequirePasswordCB.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.password_required, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //System.out.println("Empty password");
                    } else if (prefUsersPass.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                        // The above line checks to see if the User's pass is all spaces :p
                        prefRequirePasswordCB.setChecked(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.password_required, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //System.out.println("Trimmed the password because they used all spaces probably and still empty");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.password_has_been_set, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //System.out.println("kapow! they have a password and its: " + prefUsersPass.getText().toString());
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/security_pref_category">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="prefEnablePasswordLock"
            android:summary="@string/pref_require_password_for_app_description"
            android:title="@string/pref_require_password_for_app" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue=""
            android:key="prefPassword"
            android:summary="@string/pref_password_description"
            android:title="@string/pref_password_title" />
    </PreferenceCategory>


    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/look_and_feel_pref_category">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="prefDarkTheme"
            android:summary="@string/pref_dark_theme_description"
            android:title="@string/pref_dark_theme" />

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/pref_app_themes"
            android:entryValues="@array/pref_app_theme_values"
            android:key="prefMaterialThemes"
            android:summary="@string/pref_change_theme_description"
            android:title="@string/pref_change_theme" />


    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/misc_pref_category">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="linkify_note_text"
            android:summary="@string/settings_linkify_subtitle"
            android:title="@string/settings_linkify_title" />

        <Preference
            android:key="contactDevKey"
            android:summary="@string/pref_contact_developer_description"
            android:title="@string/pref_contact_developer">
            <intent
                android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="mailto:support@oxpheen.com?subject=Support *Notes">
                <extra
                    android:name="android.intent.extra.TEXT"
                    android:value="" />
                <!-- Value is whats in the body, blank for now -->
            </intent>
        </Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Arrays.xml (used in the preference.xml file to get the entries for the list preference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


    <string-array name="pref_app_themes">
        <item name="1">Default</item>
        <item name="2">Dark</item>
        <item name="3">AMOLED</item>
        <item name="4">Red</item>
        <item name="5">Pink</item>
        <item name="6">Purple</item>
        <item name="7">Deep Purple</item>
        <item name="8">Blue</item>
        <item name="9">Light Blue</item>
        <item name="10">Cyan</item>
        <item name="11">Teal</item>
        <item name="12">Green</item>
        <item name="13">Light Green</item>
        <item name="14">Lime</item>
        <item name="15">Yellow</item>
        <item name="16">Amber</item>
        <item name="17">Orange</item>
        <item name="18">Deep Orange</item>
        <item name="19">Brown</item>
        <item name="20">Grey</item>
        <item name="21">Blue Grey</item>

    </string-array>
    <string-array name="pref_app_theme_values">
        <item name="1">1</item>
        <item name="2">2</item>
        <item name="3">3</item>
        <item name="4">4</item>
        <item name="5">5</item>
        <item name="6">6</item>
        <item name="7">7</item>
        <item name="8">8</item>
        <item name="9">9</item>
        <item name="10">10</item>
        <item name="11">11</item>
        <item name="12">12</item>
        <item name="13">13</item>
        <item name="14">14</item>
        <item name="15">15</item>
        <item name="16">16</item>
        <item name="17">17</item>
        <item name="18">18</item>
        <item name="19">19</item>
        <item name="20">20</item>
        <item name="21">21</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

onSharedPreferenceChanged is called once a preference is changed. When that happens you set the OnPreferenceClickListener which will be triggered once you change the value again. That's the reason your code is executed only when changing the theme value twice.

Put this into the onCreate instead:

```
final ListPreference prefListThemes = (ListPreference) findPreference("prefMaterialThemes");
prefListThemes.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("Toasted");
        // Restart Activity to apply Theme
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I had tried that as well. It does the exact same thing. I have to select the item twice for it to work.

Comment: I believe you as I've also used it before, but this is the first time that this has happened to me. All my other preferences work fine, except this one for some reason. Digging through every inch of code to try to find anything that would even make it do that.

Comment: As a matter of fact I just tested it in one of my apps and it's called whenever the list preference is changed (shows a Toast). The code you posted certainly doesn't work so please try mine even if you've had it before. Maybe yours was (slightly) different?

Comment: If it doesn't work post your (new) code again plus the code that populates the list preference (or the xml if that's where the values come from)

Comment: I tried your code, it was also doing that. I updated the post with my preferenceactivity, preferences.xml, and arrays.xml

Comment: Try my approach again but this time move the prefListThemes.setOnPreferenceChangeListener into onCreate. It's obviously not working if that call is within the onSharedPreferenceChanged.

Comment: That immediately fires the listener but it doesn't recognize any of the radio buttons within that dialog. It'll run the code inside the method but it's like it wasn't connected. @Emanuel Moecklin

Comment: Of course it doesn't recognize the new values since you return false instead of true. I changed my answer to include the complete code. Put that one into the onCreate() and I guarantee you it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to put your code in onCreate, just change the retune type to true.

Official documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html
True to update the state of the Preference with the new value.